# Are there keyboard shortcuts for switching between or closing tabs in PyScripter?

Tags: pyscripter

The shortcuts I'm used to from a bunch of other editors is CTRL + PgUp/PgDown for switching between tabs and CTRL + w for closing tabs, but these don't seem to work in PyScripter. Are there any corresponding shortcuts in PyScripter (for Windows)?

Answer (score 2):

In PyScripter, go to `Tools > Options > IDE Shortcuts`

The default settings for -

- Closing a window is `ctrl+F4`  (found under `File > actFileClose`)
- Switching between opened files is `ctrl+Tab` (unable to find where it's configured though)

You could change it to whatever you want.
Shall look around how to edit the page-toggling short-key.